# How to store variable with pointer variable

Tags: c, pointers

I am following along with a book i am reading on C and was wondering if anyone could help me out with an issue i am having. My function must allow the user to enter a floating point number and then that number must be stored in the variable that is being pointed to by the pointer parameter. When i print the value in main i keep getting zeros. The function is only allowed to return true or false so i cant actually return the value. Here is my code:

Just looking for guidance, thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)




bool getDouble(double  *pNumber);


int main(void) 
{
    double d1 = 0;
    double *pNumber;
    bool i;


    pNumber = &d1;
    i = getDouble(pNumber);
    printf("%f", *pNumber);



}


/*
* Function: getDouble()Parameter: double *pNumber: pointer 
* to a variable that is filled in by the user input, if 
* valid
* Return Value: bool: true if the user entered a valid 
* floating-point number, false otherwise 
* Description: This function gets a floating-point number 
* from the user. If the user enters a valid floating-point 
* number, the value is put into the variable pointed to by 
* the parameter and true is returned.  If the user-entered 
* value is not valid, false is returned.
*/
bool getDouble( double  *pNumber )
{

    /* the array is 121 bytes in size; we'll see in a later lecture how we can improve this code */
    char record[121] = { 0 }; /* record stores the string */
    double number = 0.0;
    /* NOTE to student: indent and brace this function consistent with your others */
    /* use fgets() to get a string from the keyboard */
    fgets(record, 121, stdin);
    /* extract the number from the string; sscanf() returns a number
    * corresponding with the number of items it found in the string */
    if (sscanf_s(record, "%lf", &number) != 1)
    {
        /* if the user did not enter a number recognizable by
        * the system, return false */
        return false;
    }
    pNumber = &number;   /* this is where i think i am messing up */
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pNumber = &number;` just stores the address of your local variable in the parameter of your function (which also is a local variable)

What you want to do is: `*pNumber = number;`

BTW you can directly do: `if (sscanf_s(record, "%lf", pNumber) != 1)`

And your `main` could be greatly simplified and made safer:

```
int main(void) 
{
    double d1;

    pNumber = &d1;
    if (getDouble(&d1))
    {
       printf("%lf", d1);
    }
}
```

Fixes:

- unnecessary temp variables
- wrong format to print the double
- no test to see if input is valid